# how can I play a video that is encoding yet?

Tags: c#, wpf, video, mediaelement, video-encoding

I'm encoding an FLV video, and I want to show the result on my WPF application while the video is still encoding.

I use `MediaElement`, but it only plays to the total time that the video has when I open the file.

I tried to update that total time without success.

Comment: What software are you using to encode the FLV video?

Comment: Flash Media encoder 2.5

Comment: Are you able to query the length (what MediaElement retrieved upon opening the file)? Also, can you seek within the file?

Comment: @MultimediaMike, yes, I can query `MediaPlayer.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan` and I can seek within the file.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the constraints you have described, here's a solution that might work:

- When the video starts encoding, open the video for playback and query the length
- Start playing the video and monitor its playback position to determine when it's getting close to the limit determined in the previous step
- When it gets close (within a second), close the file, reopen (with a new, longer length), and seek to the previous playback location

It's not perfect and might result in a bit of visual stutter. But you might pop up some message in the UI advising the user that such stutters are expected during preview and won't affect the final video.

Comment: Thanks, now I have a basic flash player that plays the video without any problem, but I want to eliminate flash from my project. If yours is the only solution I think I will continue with the flash player without stutters.

Comment: That's reasonable. :) It's a pretty ugly hack.